# merge multidimensional array cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have a function in my appController ..i am not good in arrays so i want to merge these two functions

**First Array**

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'controlpanel'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
        'authError'=>"You can't access that page",

        'authorize'=>array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')


            )
        )
    )
);
```

**second Array**

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'columns' => array('email', 'mobileNo'),
            'userModel' => 'User',

        )
    );
```

what i want is i want to add **Second function** into **first function** if that possible

Comment: These are not function, these are just two separate arrays. What do you want and why do you want ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari  know they are two seperate arrays ..i just named them functions so that i can explain my problem more clearly ... i just want to add the 2nd array in first array..it is just for writing code more clean and managable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to merge two arrays as described in your description (not to arrange), then you should use CakePHP's Hash class, specifically the merge function. You can read more in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3amerge).

```
$merged_array = Hash::merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: so are  u saying that without $merge_array it is not possible that i can fit 2nd array into 1st

Comment: No I'm not saying that, you can name it anything you like, even $array1 = Hash::merge($array1,$array2
); please read through documentation and try things out to learn

Comment: If that doesn't give results you want read through other Hash functions like combine